# proc sql insert changes value format

Tags: sql, macros, sas

This is somewhat weired. 
I have a macro variable which is negative and by nature character. But when I insert the macro variable in the table it removes the negative symbol.

```
%put &pa_gh;
```

> 7161.28-

```
proc sql;
    insert into data_data
    values("ANV(iy)","&rd_gh","&ns_gh","&pa_gh","$0.00");
quit;
```

Value coming in the table is given below

> 7161.28

While creating the table I also specified

```
proc sql;
    create table data_data
    (   Name_of_File char(30),
        A char(16),
        B char(16),
        C char(16),
        D char(16)
    )
;
quit;
```

Comment: I can't replicate this error.  What are you creating the table in?  What are you viewing the ultimate results in?

Comment: For me it works. Be sure to check the field is really char(16) and its format. Aren't there any blanks in front of the number?

Comment: Joe, I am finally exporting to to CSV and thought that binary format of csv might be creating the trouble, though while printing it in normal sas foramt the "-" does not appears.Vasja, I did checked the format of column as Char(16)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the length of column which I gave as 16 but it was taking 20 .